# Nextflow: transform a list of tuples into a channel of tuples?

Tags: groovy, nextflow

My process returns a list of tuples. How to create a channel that yields each tuple separately?

Indeed, I want to use the tuple's item as input of another process (here the `multiply` process). I would want the calls to `multiply` (i.e. one for each tuple in `my_list_of_tuple`) to be able to run in parallel.

However, if I use:

- `my_process.out.my_returned_list`: I get only one element (`[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`);
- `my_process.out.my_returned_list.flatten()`: I also flatten the tuples and get 6 elements (`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`).

**Question:** How to define a channel that will get 3 elements: `[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]`?

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process my_process {
  output:
    val myList, emit: my_returned_list

  exec:
    myList = []
    myList.add(tuple(1, 2))
    myList.add(tuple(3, 4))
    myList.add(tuple(5, 6))
}

process multiply {
    input:
        val left
        val right

    output:
        val left_times_right

    exec:
        left_times_rigth = left * right
}

workflow {
    my_process()
    my_process.out.my_returned_list.view()
    my_process.out.my_returned_list.flatten().view()

    // <channel_to_be_defined>.map { i, j ->
    //    multiply(i, j)
    // }
}
```

Comment: `my_process.out.my_returned_list.flatten().collate(2).view()` (or `.buffer(size:2).view()` is a solution — however, it relies on me knowing that the tuples are of size 2. I would prefer a solution that keeps working if I were to return tuples of size 3 (and adapt `multiply` accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [`flatMap`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#flatmap) operator for this, for example:

```
process my_process {
    
    output:
    val myList, emit: my_returned_list

    exec:
    myList = []
    myList.add(tuple(1, 2))
    myList.add(tuple(3, 4))
    myList.add(tuple(5, 6, 7))
}

process multiply {
    
    input:
    val factors

    output:
    tuple val(factors), val(the_product)

    exec:
    the_product = factors.inject { acc, num -> acc *= num }
}
```

```
workflow {

    my_process()

    my_factors = my_process.out.flatMap()
    my_products = multiply( my_factors )

    my_products.view { factors, product ->
        "The product of ${factors.join(',')} is: ${product}"
    }
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [admiring_hilbert] DSL2 - revision: 0bafefce32
executor >  local (4)
[9d/292489] process > my_process   [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[ec/94643b] process > multiply (1) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
The product of 3,4 is: 12
The product of 5,6,7 is: 210
The product of 1,2 is: 2
```

Comment: `.flatMap` is exactly what I was looking for indeed — I just struggled figuring it out from how the operator is described in the docs!